# format from string to integer?

Tags: python

I have some problems with format from string to int in Python:

```
obj=self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)[0]
hour_den=obj.time_in[12:13]
hour_di=obj.time_out[12:13]
min_den=obj.time_in[15:16]
min_di=obj.time_out[15:16]
gl=hour_di-hour_den
pl=min_di-min_den
```

and error is:

```
 unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'
```

how can i format it ??
Help me please!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) from datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
hour_den = '12:13'
hour_di = '12:15'
FMT = '%H:%M'
timedelta = datetime.strptime(hour_di, FMT) - datetime.strptime(hour_den, FMT)
print timedelta
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what type obj is. However you could do.

```
obj=self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)[0]
hour_den = hour_di = min_den = min_di = 0
try:
  hour_den=int(obj.time_in[12:13])
  hour_di=int(obj.time_out[12:13])
  min_den=int(obj.time_in[15:16])
  min_di=int(obj.time_out[15:16])
except ValueError:
  return False
gl=hour_di-hour_den
pl=min_di-min_den
```

But better do casting to int in separete function

I suspect you indexes are incorrect.
If you need to manually parse date in fixed format like "2011-12-14 02:20:11". You could use following:

```
ts = "2011-12-14 02:20:11"
date, time = ts.split()
hours, mins, secs = time.split(':')
try:
  hours=int(hours)
  mins=int(mins)
  secs=int(secs)
except ValueError:
  return False
```

Comment: error again is
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
i do abot the hour and minues with obj.time_in is "2011-12-14 02:20:11" and i want cut minues and hour of it and convert to int. for do some calculation

Comment: This answer has one thing I've been told is the "Python" way of doing things. That is using try except. It was even explained to me I should look for non-numerics in our water account data by assigning the value of a numeric account # column to an integer in a try .. except block, instead of using an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If these are integers, you can use "int" to convert to an integer.  For example:

```
hour_den=int(obj.time_in[12:13])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gl = int(hour_di) - int(hour_den)
pl = int(min_dl) - int(min_den)
```